# Javascript callback function in blackboard pattern control flow

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have implemented a blackboard pattern in Javascript, my blackboard control iterates over knowledge sources / experts, and call their execAction().

```
for(let expert of this.blackboard.experts){ 
   // Check execution condition
}
mostRelevantExpert.executeAction();
```

Now the problem is, those knowledge sources often need to call remote APIs or read files, and most of the libraries only provide callback APIs

```
class myExpert{
  executeAction() {
    myLibrary.call(params, (error, response) => { continueHere; })
  }
}
```

Of course this is completely messing up the flow of my blackboard.

I am not sure whether the solution would be to reimplement the whole blackboard in an "asynchronous" fashion, or if there's a smarter way to go.

I've tried using libraries like deasync, but the problem is that I actually have a bug in `myLibrary.call(params, (error, response) => { bueHere; }` and I do not really understand now how to debug it. Since I am likely to have more problems like that in the future, was wondering what actions I should take.

Using node 6, ES6, and I don't like using callback programming style for what I'm doing here.

- How should I go about the blackboard pattern in Javascript ?
- How can I debug async code using `node debug app.js`

EDIT :

Here is my Blackboard Control code :

```
module.exports = class BlackboardControl{
  constructor(blackboard){
    this.blackboard = blackboard;
  }

  loop(){
    console.log('¤ Blackboard Control');
    console.log('    Starting Blackboard loop');

    // Problem solved when there is a technicianAnswer, so the bot has something to say
    while(!this.blackboard.problemSolved) {

      // Select experts who can contribute to the problem
      let candidates = [];
      for(let expert of this.experts){
        let eagerness = expert.canContribute();
        if(eagerness){
          candidates.push([eagerness,expert]);
        }
      }

      if(candidates.length === 0) {
        console.log('No expert can\'t do anything, returning');
        return;
      }

      // Sort them by eagerness
      candidates.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a[0]-b[0];
      });
      for(let eagerExpert of candidates){
        console.log('Next expert elected : ' + eagerExpert[1].constructor.name);
        eagerExpert[1].execAction();

      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you considered using promises for controlling asynchronous flow? I recommend looking into what bluebird.js has to offer, especially with regard to wrapping existing, node-style callback APIs with minimal effort (promisification).

Comment: You may also want to look into [async/await](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/) as it turns async code into a more familiar linear process.

Comment: @ArcSine oh nice, very interesting link.

Comment: @Tomalak then please show me how you would use promises in the code I have added in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt based on my (incomplete) understanding of your problem. These are the premises I used:

- you have `Expert` objects that provide an asynchronous function that does some kind of work via the `executeAction()` method.
- you have a `BlackboardControl` object that pools these experts and is responsible for running them in sequence until one of them returns a successful result. This object is also holding some kind of state encapsulated in the `blackboard` property.

The first step to a promise-based solution is to make the `executeAction()` method return a promise instead of requiring a callback. Changing the call convention of an entire node-style library is easily done with the [`promisifyAll()` utility](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html) that Bluebird provides:

```
// module MyExpert ---------------------------------------------------------
var Promise = require('bluebird');

// dummy library with a node-style async function, let's promisify it
var myLibrary = Promise.promisifyAll({
  someFunc: function (params, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (Math.random() < 0.4) callback('someFunc failed');
      else callback(null, {inputParams: params});
    }, Math.random() * 1000 + 100);
  }
});

class MyExpert {
  executeAction(params) {
    return myLibrary.someFuncAsync(params);  // returns a promise!
  }
}

module.exports = MyExpert;
```

now, we need a `BlackboardControl` object that does two things: pull out the next free `Expert` object from the pool (`nextAvailableExpert()`) and solve a given problem by applying experts to it in sequence, until one of them succeeds or a maximum retry count is reached (`solve()`).

```
// module BlackboardControl ------------------------------------------------
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var MyExpert = require('./MyExpert');

class BlackboardControl {
  constructor(blackboard) {
    this.blackboard = blackboard;
    this.experts = [/* an array of experts */];
  }

  nextAvailableExpert() {
    return new MyExpert();

    // yours would look more like this
    return this.experts
      .map((x) => ({eagerness: x.canContribute(), expert: x}))
      .filter((ex) => ex.eagerness > 0)
      .sort((exA, exB) => exA.eagerness - exB.eagerness)
      .map((ex) => ex.expert)
      .pop();
  }

  solve(options) {
    var self = this;
    var expert = this.nextAvailableExpert();

    if (!expert) {
      return Promise.reject('no expert available');
    } else {
      console.info('Next expert elected : ' + expert.constructor.name);
    }

    options = options || {};
    options.attempt = +options.attempt || 0;
    options.maxAttempts = +options.maxAttempts || 10;

    return expert.executeAction(/* call parameters here */).catch(error => {
      options.attempt++;
      console.error("failed to solve in attempt " + options.attempt + ": " + error);
      if (options.attempt <= options.maxAttempts) return self.solve(options);
      return Promise.reject("gave up after " + options.maxAttempts + " attempts.");
    });
  }
}

module.exports = BlackboardControl;
```

The key line is this one:

```
if (options.attempt <= options.maxAttempts) return self.solve(options);
```

Promises chain. If you return a new promise from a promise callback (in this case from the `catch()` handler, since we want to start over when an expert fails) the overall result of the promise will be determined by the result of this new promise. In other words, the new promise will be executed. This is our iterative step.

This way returning a promise from `solve()` enables internal repetition by simply calling `solve()` again in the error handler - and it enables reacting externally via `then()` as shown in below example usage:

```
// usage -------------------------------------------------------------------
var BlackboardControl = require('./BlackboardControl');
var bbControl = new BlackboardControl({ /* blackboard object */ });

var result = bbControl.solve({
  maxAttempts: 10
}).then(response => {
  console.log("continueHere: ", response);
}).catch(reason => {
  console.error(reason);
});
```

which creates output like this (here dummy function happened to fail five times in a row):

```
Next expert elected : MyExpert
failed to solve in attempt 1: Error: someFunc failed
Next expert elected : MyExpert
failed to solve in attempt 2: Error: someFunc failed
Next expert elected : MyExpert
failed to solve in attempt 3: Error: someFunc failed
Next expert elected : MyExpert
failed to solve in attempt 4: Error: someFunc failed
Next expert elected : MyExpert
failed to solve in attempt 5: Error: someFunc failed
Next expert elected : MyExpert
continueHere:  { some: 'parameters' }
```

During expert runs control is returned to the main program. Due to the fact that now multiple experts can run at the same time on multiple problems we can't make a list of available experts up-front. We must make a fresh decision every time we need an expert, hence the `nextAvailableExpert()` function.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't actually tried it out, yet (largely because I'd have to invent arbitrary problem spaces, and I feel like it would be much easier traveling in the other direction, right now)...

But if you want a look at what an async flow might look like, I might consider something like this:

```
async function getEngagedExperts (experts, problem) {
  const getContributor = expert => expert.canContribute(problem)
    .then(eagerness => [eagerness, expert]);

  const contributors = await Promise.all(experts.map(getContributor));
  return contributors.filter(([eager]) => eager);
}


async function contribute (previousState, expert) {
  const state = await previousState;
  return expert.execAction(state);
}


async function solveProblem (problem, experts) {
  if (problem.solved) { return problem; }

  const candidates = (await getEngagedExperts(experts, problem))
    .sort(([a], [b]) => a - b)
    .map(([, expert]) => expert);

  const result = await candidates.reduce(contribute, Promise.resolve(problem));
  return candidates.length ? solveProblem(result, experts) : undefined;
}
```

## ES6 Generators + Yield

Works in ES6, if you have a library like `co` to manage the promises returned from iterators.
Writing your own co implementation is not that difficult, but this is totally not the space for it.

```
const getEngagedExperts = co.wrap(function * getEngagedExperts (experts, problem) {
  const getContributor = expert => expert.canContribute(problem)
    .then(eagerness => [eagerness, expert]);

  const contributors = yield Promise.all(experts.map(getContributor));
  return contributors.filter(([eager]) => eager);
});


const contribute = co.wrap(function * contribute (previousState, expert) {
  const state = yield previousState;
  return expert.execAction(state);
});


const solveProblem = co.wrap(function * solveProblem (problem, experts) {
  if (problem.solved) { return problem; }

  const candidates = (yield getEngagedExperts(experts, problem)))
    .sort(([a], [b]) => a - b)
    .map(([, expert]) => expert);

  const result = yield candidates.reduce(contribute, Promise.resolve(problem));
  return candidates.length ? solveProblem(result, experts) : undefined;
});
```

## ES5 + Promise

When all else fails, write it by hand, in good ol' ES5, plus promises.

```
function getEngagedExperts (experts, problem) {
  function getContributor (expert) {
    return expert.canContribute(problem).then(eagerness => [eagerness, expert]);
  }

  function filterContributors (contributors) {
    return contributors.filter(function (pair) {
      const eagerness = pair[0];
      return eagerness;
    });
  }

  const getContributors = Promise.all(experts.map(getContributor));
  return getContributors.then(filterContributors);
}


function contribute (previousComputation, expert) {
  return previousComputation.then(function (state) {
    return expert.execAction(state);
  });
}


function solveProblem (problem, experts) {
  if (problem.solved) { return problem; }

  const getCandidates = getEngagedExperts(experts, problem)
  .then(function (candidates) {
    return candidates
      .sort(function (a, b) { return a[0] - b[0]; })
      .map(function (pair) { return pair[1]; });
  });

  return getCandidates.then(function (candidates) {
    const getResult = candidates.reduce(contribute, Promise.resolve(problem));
    return getResult.then(function (result) {
      return candidates.length ? solveProblem(result, experts) : undefined;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid there is no nodejs version that supports this `await` stuff yet ?

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris
No.
There will soon be support in V8, in Chrome Canary (and eventually Chrome and Node). To handle Async/Await, you would run it through a transpiler like Babel.

However, there is also nothing stopping you from doing the exact same thing using promises, except chaining with `then` in all places I'm using `await`, and after all points where I call an `async` function. I believe that would actually be the full extent of the changes made.

Comment: The problem I see with this code is the point that a fixed `candidates` list will not be valid over consecutive invocations. A candidate back in the list might already be solving a different problem by the time `reduce()` reaches it.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm not entirely sure where you're going with that. The recursive invocation is getting the full list of experts, the candidates are chosen, filtered and sorted based on the state of the problem at the invocation of the function (same as above), each function is operating on the state of the system in turn, one after the other, in the reduce (what I assume is the same as above), undefined is returned in the case of 0 candidates, and the recursion takes the place of the while.

Comment: @Tomalak if your point is that in the reduce, I am taking the list of all experts and mangling the state, as they have no real means of guaranteeing that they're still contributing to the initial problem, I get that.
But that's in the original algorithm in the question, and has little to do with how I set this up.
Had the algorithm just expected the most-qualified expert, I would have simply said `head(candidates)` and been done with it.

Comment: I'm assuming that there is a fixed pool of "experts" that might be doing work even for parallel invocations of `solveProblem()`. When a predetermined list is assembled at point-in-time A, and then reduced one-by-one, the same expert instance might be part of a different list running at the same time, so a race condition might occur at point-in-time B, when the same expert might be "up next" in the list in two different contexts. I might be wrong with that thought, though.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was in the original code, but only because the OP chose to "deasync" the worker functions, thus guaranteeing execution order.

Comment: @Tomalak that's fair. That's actually why my solution passes `problem` throughout, as my expectation is that the experts (at least in my system) would be stateless, and passed the problem (both in the "can you do this" and the "do it" calls). I'm pretty sure I didn't miss any async connections to guarantee flow, here. As long as the "experts" in the list are themselves stateless (and passed the state), I'm not seeing how this wouldn't be threadsafe / concurrency-safe. If the experts needed to be locked down, then they could be instances with closure reference to the particular blackboard.

Comment: Yeah, I was just throwing in the thought. As I was saying, I wasn't sure about whether that was an actual issue or not in the first place. Apart from the fact that Node does not understand the syntax yet I think it's nicer than my attempt.

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris I've included two solutions which require no transpilation. One does require a helper library ("co" or something like it),  which can be written by hand, if you're up to it. The other is a pretty straightforward head-down ES5 implementation of this, which just depends on spec compliant Promise support.

Comment: @Tomalak see above edits for the ES6 / ES5 implementations.

Answer (score -1):

Ah right, I actually managed to make the deasync code work. It turns out I was trying to use

```
const deasync = require('deasync');

try {
    const deasyncAnswer = deasync(Lib.foo(
      myParam,
      // Callback was here
    );
}
```

But the correct way to use it was

```
const fooDeasynced= deasync(Lib.foo);
try {
    const deasyncAnswer = fooDeasynced(myparams)
}
```

Comment: Turning async code into blocking code is rarely a good idea. Even more so if it's just for the developer's convenience.

Comment: then please show me an example of a blackboard pattern implementation using promises as control flow.